# Google map do not drag on wp enfold theme in my web site?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, tenfold

Hi i am work at wordpress. I am add a google map from widget. Google map showing but google map not darg but why...?
I can't solv that! Please Help me any one.

My Web site is URL: http://castleinchvenue.ie/home/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

which browser you are using?
I'm using firefox and google map drag is working here.